# Trouble running MongoDB server on macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: mongodb, homebrew, macos-monterey

I've installed MongoDB through Homebrew and when I start the server using `brew services start mongodb-community` (or mongodb-community@5.0) command it immediately fails and turn the `brew services list` to error!

I already tried giving permission - using Rosetta to install and run - etc. but ended up with the same error.

The only thing I don't know how do (which might potentially work) is to change the directory of MongoDB, but I am not sure that could be a solution or not!

Comment: what is the error ?
do you see anything in the mongod.log ?

Comment: ```brew services start mongodb-community``` shows this:
```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/503 /Users/alex/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5.
```

Comment: and log shows:
```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T08:01:45.845+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"Checkpointer","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1637647305:845904][300:0x30b717000], WT_SESSION.checkpoint: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 2234, snapshot max: 2234 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 16223"}}
```

Comment: did you try to run mongodb as process ?

'''mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf --fork'''

see if this changes anything .

Comment: Tried: mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork
Result:
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 23103
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 1

Comment: run the command again without the -fork option. 
because  you have have a misconfigured mongod.conf file

Comment: Result:
{"t":{"$date":"2021-11-23T15:33:02.647Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Error during global initialization","attr":{"error":{"code":38,"codeName":"FileNotOpen","errmsg":"Can't initialize rotatable log file :: caused by :: Failed to open /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}

Comment: Even when it doesn't show the error, it just doesn't return anything and there is no service up!

Comment: perhaps it's a permission issue.
 try starting   "sudo mongod  ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unloading and loading launchctl solved the permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running below command after installation of mongodb:

```
sudo brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
```

Then running `sudo brew services list` will show the mongodb-commuity service status to started.